# UISearchBar is not searching when entering text

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a Table View that is working fine. However, when I try to implement a UISearchBar and display filtered data, nothing gets filtered. This is my View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class MealPlanViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    private var model = MealPlanModel()
    private var mealPlan = [MealPlan]()
    var filteredData: [MealPlan]!
        
    @IBOutlet weak var topBarStackView: UIStackView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        model.delegate = self
        
        searchBar.delegate = self
        
        filteredData = mealPlan
    }
    
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        
        filteredData = []
        
        if searchText == "" {
            filteredData = mealPlan
        }
        else {
            
            for item in mealPlan {
                
                if ((item.title?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) != nil) {

                    filteredData.append(item)
                }
            }
        }
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
}

extension MealPlanViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MealPlanCell", for: indexPath) as! MealPlanCell
        
        let filteredMealPlaninTable = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.displayMealPlan(filteredMealPlaninTable)
                
        return cell
    }
        
}

extension MealPlanViewController: MealPlanProtocol {
    
    func mealPlansRetrieved(mealPlans: [MealPlan]) {
        
        self.filteredData = mealPlans
        
        tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
}
```

A couple of notes:

1. When I run a `print(self.filteredData)` in my `func mealPlansRetrieved', the console returns all of my data as if it wasn't filtered, but
2. As soon as I start typing in the search bar, the table view doesn't return any cells, which seems contradictory to the above

For reference, this is the code before filtering that did work:

```
extension MealPlanViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mealPlan.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MealPlanCell", for: indexPath) as! MealPlanCell
        
        let mealPlanInTable = mealPlan[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.displayMealPlan(mealPlanInTable)

        return cell
    }
}

extension MealPlanViewController: MealPlanProtocol {
    
    func mealPlansRetrieved(mealPlans: [MealPlan]) {
        
        self.mealPlan = mealPlans
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Any help/guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Contains returns boolean so this will never fail: item.title?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) != nil

To make check work you can simply remove "!= nil".

Im not sure from where you are calling mealPlansRetrieved, but you might want to keep the line "self.mealPlan = mealPlans" instead of "self.filteredData = mealPlans".

Comment: Thank you! I think the issue might be that I need the searchText to update my Firestore query. I'm doing some more digging.